# Commuting matrices and cyclic modules

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-groups, modules, flag-varieties

Let $A, B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be matrices that commute. We suppose that there exists a vector $v\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $(\mathbb{C}[A,B]).v$ generates $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. We call such a pair a cyclic pair.

Is there only a finite number of flags that are stabilized both by  $A$ and $B$?

Note, that if we already know that $A$ or $B$ is a cyclic endomorphism, then it is the case.

Comment: In $(\mathbb C[A.B]).v$, you're adjoining the ordinary matrix product $A B$, not using some funny notation for the commutator, right?

Comment: @LSpice there's no commutator involved. $\mathbf{C}[A,B]$ denotes here the unital $\mathbf{C}$-subalgebra generated by $A,B$.

Comment: @YCor, but it is $\mathbb C[A.B]$, not $\mathbb C[A, B]$.

Comment: @LSpice ah, I see. I guess this is a typo and OP means C[A,B], not C[A.B] (otherwise the assumption are quite absurd).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then your hypotheses are satisfied, with $v=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, and there are infinitely many flags stabilised by $A$ and $B$ as long as your field $\mathbb C$ is infinite. The point is that you can start with the span of some linear combination of the second and third basis elements as your one dimensional subspace, stabilised by $A$ and $B$, and then the rest of the flag is determined. Presuming that $\mathbb C$ denotes the complex numbers, this should answer your question.

P.S. I've assumed that your $\mathbb{C}[A.B]$ is a misprint for $\mathbb{C}[A,B]$, the algebra generated over $\mathbb C$ by the commuting elements $A$ and $B$.